# Switch statement with conditional type. performance vs readability

Tags: c++

I am writing a switch statement that selects a string to display based on an enum and condition. Option 1 is clearly more readable, but I don't know if Option 2 is better in any way. I haven't been able to benchmark. Is there a clear rule here or is it premature optimization?

Option 1:

```
switch (enum_type)
{
    case option_a: 
        return condition ? choice1 : choice2;
    case option_b:
        return condition ? choice3 : choice4;
    case option_c:
        return condition ? choice5 : choice6;
    default:
        return condition ? default1 : default2;
};
```

or

Option 2:

```
if (condition)
{
    switch (enum_type)
    {
        case option_a: 
            return choice1;
        case option_b:
            return choice3;
        case option_c:
            return choice5;
        default:
            return default1;
    };
}
else
{
    switch (enum_type)
    {
        case option_a: 
            return choice2;
        case option_b:
            return choice4;
        case option_c:
            return choice6;
        default:
            return default2;
    };
}
```

Comment: This is what you would call a premature pessimization. First of all, there's most likely zero performance difference. Secondly, even if there is, the compiler optimizes it out (gcc 11.2 seems to produce the same assembly code no matter which one you choose). Prefer readability (option 1).

Comment: Why not put the choices in a `static const char *const table[max_enum][2];` and then do `table[enum_type][!!condition];`? Good compact code guaranteed, and no switch+if, just a table lookup. The equivalent can also be done with a switch (`switch(enum_type*2+!!condition){ case option_a*2+0: ... case option_a*2+1: ... `).

Comment: @PSkocik would `!!` really be needed? `bool` has implicit conversion to `int` no?

Comment: @Offtkp Not if you're certain that `condition` isn't anything other than 0 or 1. (If it's bool typed, an optimizing compiler will be certain too and delete the `!!`, so it shouldn't do any harm in any case).

Comment: A matter of opinion apparently, but I find Option2 a lot more readable. Having `if (condition)` appear only once makes it clear (to me) that it is the _same_ condition everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If your enumerators just go from 0 to `options_num` one by one, I think there's a both shorter and faster way:

```
enum Option { option_a, option_b, option_c };
auto constexpr options_num = 3u;

enum Choice { // just some random numbers to return to see the compiler output
    choice1, choice2 = 3, choice3 = 42, choice4,
    choice5 = 4, choice6, default1 = 37, default2 = 522
};

constexpr auto match1(Option enum_type, bool condition) { // your option
    switch (enum_type) {
        case option_a: return condition ? choice1 : choice2;
        case option_b: return condition ? choice3 : choice4;
        case option_c: return condition ? choice5 : choice6;
        default: return condition ? default1 : default2;
    }
}

constexpr auto match2(Option enum_type, bool condition) { // my idea
    std::array constexpr table{
        choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4,
        choice5, choice6, default1, default2
    };
    return table[(enum_type <= option_c ? enum_type : options_num) * (condition + 1)];
}

// tests
static_assert(match1(option_a, true) == match2(option_a, true));
static_assert(match1(option_b, true) == match2(option_b, true));
static_assert(match1(option_c, true) == match2(option_c, true));
static_assert(match2(option_a, false) == match2(option_a, false));
static_assert(match2(option_b, false) == match2(option_b, false));
static_assert(match2(option_c, false) == match2(option_c, false));
static_assert(match2((Option)322, true) == match2((Option)322, true));
static_assert(match2((Option)322, false) == match2((Option)322, false));
```

x86-64 gcc 1.12 -O3:

```
match1(Option, bool):
        cmpl    $1, %edi
        je      .L2
        cmpl    $2, %edi
        je      .L3
        cmpb    $1, %sil
        sbbl    %eax, %eax
        testl   %edi, %edi
        je      .L9
        andl    $485, %eax
        addl    $37, %eax
        ret
.L2:
        movzbl  %sil, %esi
        movl    $43, %eax
        subl    %esi, %eax
        ret
.L9:
        andl    $3, %eax
        ret
.L3:
        movzbl  %sil, %esi
        movl    $5, %eax
        subl    %esi, %eax
        ret
```

```
match2(Option, bool):
        movl    $3, %eax
        movzbl  %sil, %esi
        movdqa  .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        cmpl    %eax, %edi
        cmovg   %eax, %edi
        addl    $1, %esi
        movaps  %xmm0, -40(%rsp)
        movdqa  .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
        imull   %edi, %esi
        movaps  %xmm0, -24(%rsp)
        movl    -40(%rsp,%rsi,4), %eax
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   3
        .long   42
        .long   43
.LC1:
        .long   4
        .long   5
        .long   37
        .long   522
```

Please correct me if my assumptions are wrong.

Edit: also see @PSkocik's comments.